# Tree not being created

Tags: c++, class, oop, tree, definition

When I call the function createBst(), the program gets terminated in the function.

I put a print statement after the function but it is not called.The next print statement "terminated" is not called

```
int main(){
    bst b;
    b.createBst();
    std::cout<<"terminated"<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
class node{
public:
    int val;
    node* left;
    node* right;
};

class bst{

public:
    node* head;
    void createBst();
    node* newNode(int val);

};

node* bst::newNode(int v){
    node n1;
    node* n=&n1;
    n->val=v;
    n->left=nullptr;
    n->right=nullptr;
    return n;
}

void bst::createBst(){
    head=bst::newNode(10);
    head->left=bst::newNode(11);
    (head->left)->left=bst::newNode(7);
    head->right=bst::newNode(9);
    (head->right)->left=bst::newNode(15);
    (head->right)->right=bst::newNode(8);
}
```

the output should be "terminated".

Comment: The classes shall be defined before their usage in main.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters the classes shall be defined before their usage in main.

This function

```
node* bst::newNode(int v){
    node n1;
    node* n=&n1;
    n->val=v;
    n->left=nullptr;
    n->right=nullptr;
    return n;
}
```

invokes undefined behavior because it returns pointer ro a local variable `n1` that will not be alive after exiting the function.

The function could be defined the following way

```
node* bst::newNode(int v)
{
    return new node { v, nullptr, nullptr };
}
```

In fact the function can be a private static member function

```
class bst{
public:
    node* head;
    void createBst();

private:
    static node* newNode(int val);
};
```

And the class node should be a nested private (or protected) class of the class bst.

Also you need either a default constructor for the class bst that will initialize head to nullptr or you have to explicitly initialize head to nullptr in the class definition like

```
class bst{

public:
    node* head = nullptr;
    void createBst();

private:
    static node* newNode(int val);

};
```

To insert a data into the tree you should write a function for example like this

```
void insert( int value )
{
    node **current = &head;

    while ( *current != nullptr )
    {
        if ( value < ( *current )->val )
        {
            current = &( *current )->left;
        }
        else
        {
            current = &( *current )->right;
        }
    }

    *current = newNode( value );
}
```

Comment: deleting previous comment